# How to perform aggregation and counting in a Dataset using R?

Tags: r, count, aggregate, prediction, summarize

I'm currently working with a Cricket (a sport) dataset where I need to find the accumulated runs scored, balls bowled per year with the years count. Below is an excerpt of the dataset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHDIM.png)

I'm trying to aggregate as below, but I'm not able to frame the right piece of code for this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arXxY.png)

Please help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions. SO respondents expect a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including sample data. A screenshot is not useful. Please use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49555517/edit) to revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

This should create the data frame you have:

```
cricket_df <- data.frame(Team1 = rep("DD", 7), Team2 = rep("CSK", 7), year = c(2008, 2008, 2009,2009, 2009, 2010, 2010), balls=c(4,4,2,1,2,3,2), runs=c(4,6,6,0,3,1,8))
```

And with this you can aggregate:

```
aggregate(cricket_df[c("balls", "runs")], by=list(cricket_df$Team1, cricket_df$Team2, cricket_df$year), FUN=sum)
```

Comment: But, with this code we could not obtain year_count. How to get that?

Comment: True. There may be more elegant ways, but here's a solution that should work: save the aggregate in a new dataframe:
`aggr_df <- aggregate(cricket_df[c("balls", "runs")], by=list(cricket_df$Team1, cricket_df$Team2, cricket_df$year), FUN=sum)` and a column for year count:  
`aggr_df$year_count <- table(cricket_df$year)`

Comment: Thanks it works. But with a dataset as below it dosen't provide the expected results  df <- data.frame(Team1 = c("DD","DD","DD","DD","DD","DD","DD","RR","RR","RR","RR","RR","RR","RR"), Team2 = rep("CSK", 14), year = c(2008, 2008, 2009,2009, 2009, 2010, 2010,2008, 2008, 2009,2009, 2009, 2010, 2010), balls=c(4,4,2,1,2,3,2,4,4,2,1,2,3,2), runs=c(4,6,6,0,3,1,8,4,4,2,1,2,3,2))
aggr_df <- aggregate(cricket_df[c("balls", "runs")], by=list(cricket_df$Team1, cricket_df$Team2, cricket_df$year), FUN=sum)

aggr_df$year_count <- table(df$year)